# Automatic margins in top side nav bar?

Tags: html, css

I noticed every time I try to make a nav bar I have a left and top margin of about 8px that is just there.. I have no idea where this came from as my css file is small and I do not have that code anywhere. I'm beginning to think it's some type of standard and perhaps I am doing it all wrong. How would I overcome this problem? I added a -8px margin to the left and top of the tool bar and it is now flush with the browser; however, now there is empty space if the user horizontally scrolls to the right.

[image: Take a look at the margins on the top nav bar]

### CSS

```
body {
}

.navbar-container {
width: 100%;
background-color: #252122;
/*margin-left:-8px;
margin-top:-8px;*/
}

    .navbar-container table {
    width: auto;
    }


.classifieds-container {
overflow: hidden;
z-index: -1;
top: 40px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
display: block;
width: 960px;
padding-bottom: 25px;
background: #fff;
box-shadow: 1px 0 7px;
font: 11px "Arial",sans-serif;
color: #000;
/*line-height: 59px;*/
}

    .classifieds-container label {
    color: blue;
    }

        .classifieds-container label:hover {
        color: red;
        text-decoration: underline;
        }

    .classifieds-container table {
    width: 960px;
    }

    .classifieds-container .col {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    }

.col-one {
margin-top: 60px;
float: left;
margin-left: 200px;
max-width: 175px;
text-wrap: normal;
}

    .col-one h3 {
    text-align: center;
    }

.row-splitter {
border-bottom: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: gray;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.classified-link-descriptor {
color: gray;
text-decoration: none;
font: 11px "Arial",sans-serif;
margin-bottom: 5px;
display: block;
}

nav {
display: block;
}

.logo-header {
height: 35px;
width: auto;
float: right;
}
```

### HTML

```
<body>
 <nav>
    <div id="Navigation">
        <div class="navbar-container">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">

                            <img class="logo-header" src="~/Content/logo_black_background.png" />

                        </td>

                        <td colspan="6">
                            <div>
                                @(Html.Kendo().Menu()
  .Name("Menu")
  .Items(items =>
  {
      items.Add()
          .Text("Home");
      items.Add()
          .Text("Classifieds")
          .Content(@<text>
                                <div class="classifieds-container">
                                    <div id="col1" class="col">
                                        <div id="col1-row1">
                                            <h2>Auto</h2>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row-splitter">
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            @*@Html.ActionLink("Custom Builds", "Index", "ResultsList", new { TypeOfPart = gcaMusicExchange.StaticData.ItemType.Build }, new { @class = "classified-link" })*@
                                            <label id="Custom-Builds">Custom Builds</label>
                                            <div class="classified-link-descriptor">Modified vehicles ready to drive</div>
                                            @*@Html.ActionLink("Shells", "Index", "ResultsList", new { TypeOfPart = gcaMusicExchange.StaticData.ItemType.Shell }, new { @class = "classified-link" })*@
                                            <label id="Shells">Shells</label>
                                            <div class="classified-link-descriptor">Non-running vehicles for parts</div>
                                            @*@Html.ActionLink("Stockers", "Index", "ResultsList", new { TypeOfPart = gcaMusicExchange.StaticData.ItemType.Stock }, new { @class = "classified-link" })*@
                                            <label id="Stockers">Stockers</label>
                                            <div class="classified-link-descriptor">Stock vehicles ready to drive</div>
                                            @* @Html.ActionLink("All Types", "Index", "ResultsList", new { TypeOfPart = gcaMusicExchange.StaticData.ItemType.AllTypesOfVehicles }, new { @class = "classified-link" })*@
                                            <label id="All-Types">All Types</label>
                                            <div class="classified-link-descriptor">Browse all types of vehicles in one search</div>
                                            @* @Html.ActionLink("By Year, Make, & Model", "VehiclesByMake", "Browse", null, new { @class = "classified-link" })*@
                                            <label id="YearMakeModel">By Year, Make, & Model</label>
                                            <div class="classified-link-descriptor">Search by specific year, make, and model</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="col2" class="col">
                                        <div id="col2-row1">
                                            <h2>Parts</h2>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row-splitter">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="auto-links">
                                            <label id="Browse-all-parts">Browse all parts</label>
                                            @*@Html.ActionLink("Browse all parts", "Index", "ResultsList", null, new { @class = "classified-link" })*@
                                            <div class="classified-link-descriptor">Browse all parts with no discrimination!</div>
                                            <label id="Browse-by-vehicle-application">Browse by vehicle application</label>
                                            @*@Html.ActionLink("Browse by vehicle application", "PerformancePartsByVehicle", "Browse", null, new { @class = "classified-link" })*@
                                            <div class="classified-link-descriptor">By year, make, and model</div>
                                            @*@Html.ActionLink("Browse by part category", "PerformancePartsByCategory", "Browse", null, new { @class = "classified-link" })*@
                                            <label id="Browse-by-part-category">Browse by part category</label>
                                            <div class="classified-link-descriptor">By category (e.g. turbos, intake, engine builds, etc.)</div>
                                            @*@Html.ActionLink("Browse by part manufacturer", "PerformancePartsByManufacturerLetter", "Browse", null, new { @class = "classified-link" })*@
                                            <label id="Browse-by-part-manufacturer">Browse by part manufacturer</label>
                                            <div class="classified-link-descriptor">By manufacturer (e.g. Blouch, Stance, K&N, AEM, etc.)</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="col3" class="col">
                                        <div id="col3-row1">
                                            <h2>Wheels</h2>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row-splitter">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="auto-links">
                                            @*@Html.ActionLink("Browse all wheels", "Index", "ResultsList", null, new { @class = "classified-link" })*@
                                            <label id="Browse-all-wheels">Browse all wheels</label>
                                            <div class="classified-link-descriptor">Browse all wheels with no discrimination!</div>
                                            @*@Html.ActionLink("Browse by size", "PerformancePartsByVehicle", "Browse", null, new { @class = "classified-link" })*@
                                            <label id="Browse-by-size">Browse by size</label>
                                            <div class="classified-link-descriptor">15", 18" x 11.5", 19" x 12.5" etc.</div>
                                            @* @Html.ActionLink("Browse by manufacturer", "PerformancePartsByCategory", "Browse", null, new { @class = "classified-link" })*@
                                            <label id="Browse-by-manufacturer">Browse by manufacturer</label>
                                            <div class="classified-link-descriptor">By manufacturer (e.g. Volk, Ray's, Work, Enkei, etc.)</div>
                                            @*@Html.ActionLink("Tires only", "PerformancePartsByCategory", "Browse", null, new { @class = "classified-link" })*@
                                            <label id="Tires-only">Tires only</label>
                                            <div class="classified-link-descriptor">Tires only! No rims here!</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </text>);
      items.Add()
          .Text("Search")
          .Items(children =>
              {
                  children.Add().Text("Showroom");
                  children.Add().Text("JDM gear heads");
              });

      items.Add().Text("Discussions");

      //if (WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)
      //{
      //    items.Add().Text("Account");
      //}
      //else
      //{
      //    items.Add().Text("Sign In");
      //    items.Add().Text("Register");
      //}
  }
))
                            </div>
                        </td>

                        <td colspan="2"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div>
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried to create a simple HTML using the same CSS, your HTML code seems to be dynamic. And i believe that our controls default settings are causing this additional margin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have already stated, setting a `margin` of *0* on the *body* will do the trick. I just wanted to explain little further.

The `margin: 8px` declaration is the default User Agent (in this case Chrome browser) styling. There is nothing stopping from another browser to implement another different default styling value. Best practice is often is to use a reset CSS which will reset the default browser CSS to the same values so you can start your development with a consistent base styling. [NormalizeCSS](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css) is one of many good options. If you look into its contents it has among many other useful declarations:

```
/**
* Remove default margin.
*/

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: So this style sheet you linked to will pretty much offer me a type of 'clean slate' to start off on all my projects? I had no idea user-agents imposed their own defaults -_-. Why does web development feel so unorganized compared to desktop development!

Comment: Also marking right since the answer had the most info.

Comment: Thanks! Yep, think of it as a clean consistent slate. Having each vendor implement its own behavior is a double-edged sword: the pain of cross-browser development vs the many cool innovations pushing the boundaries/possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

add below in css.

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default `body` take `8px` margin so you have to give `margin:0` in `body`

```
    body, html {
         margin:0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**body has default margins on all browsers**

So you should have

```
body, html {
         margin:0;
         padding: 0;

    }
```

**OR**

```
body, html {
             margin:0;
             padding: 0;
              overflow-x:hidden;
        }
```

**OR**

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```